# How to make form.cleaned_data[] with m2m field, string + manytomanyfield?- Django

Tags: django, forms, sendmessage, manytomanyfield, m2m

I changed a CharField of teacher into ManyToManyField, now my UserMessage and EmailMessage are broken,

models as below:

```
class UserMessage(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="recipent")
    send_user = models.ForeignKey(Use,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="sender")
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    test_name =models.CharField(max_length=800, default='', blank=True)
    test_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    test_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now)

    `# when teacher is not ManyToManyField, the EmailMessage of body works well with test.teacher.user`
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="+")
```

`test.teacher.username` is for CharField, how to define a ManyToManyField?

```
body="Name of test：" + test.name  + "，Date ：" + str(test.date) + "，Time：" + str(test.time) + ", Teachers：" + test.teacher.username
```

And partial views.py of UserMessage as below(Not whole code), the function of UserMessage works well , but I would like to know how to change `form.cleaned_data['teacher'].username` into a ManyToManyFiled? I mean it's not `form.cleaned_data['teacher.set()']` or anything else, thank you so much for any advice.

```
user_message.test_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
user_message.teacher = form.cleaned_data['teacher'].username
user_message.test_time = form.cleaned_data['time']
user_message.test_date = form.cleaned_data['date']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a User instance when you want to set a foreignkey, not one of its fields. Assuming teacher is a User object you can use something like

```
for user_teacher in form.cleaned_data['teacher']:
    user_message.teacher.add(user_teacher)
```

If you did not pass on a User instance (but say a username only) you will somehow have to select the relevant teacher(s) and then add the m2m relation, e.g.

```
user_teacher = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), username=form.cleaned_data['teacher'])
user_message.teacher.add(user_teacher)
```

which would work assuming your usernames are unique.

Comment: Hi, about UserMessage, I already Assumed teacher as a User object with `user_message1.user.add(teacher)`, I only pasted partial code of views.py, program works well, I just don't know how to define m2m field of `form.cleaned_data['teacher']`,  it's not form.cleaned_data['teacher.set()'] or form.cleaned_data['teachers'], I was trapped in this.

Comment: assuming you have some sort of template where you actually select a teacher or multiple teachers form.cleaned_data['teacher'] itself is a set. So you can iterate over it, e.g. for user_teacher in form.cleaned_data['teacher']

Comment: Messages need to send to many students and many teachers, could you please show me some samples about iterating over it, thank you so much